# Does Ubuntu have drivers for an IBM Thinkpad T40?

Tags: drivers, thinkpad, compatibility

Does Ubuntu have drivers available for this laptop?

And which version of Ubuntu would be recommended for the T40?

---

[T40 specs for reference](http://www.kaileypc.com/files/info/IBM_T40.pdf)

- CPU: Pentium M 1.3-1.6 GHz
- Video: ATI Radeon 7500 32MB
- RAM: 256 MB standard/2GB max
- Connectivity: Intel Fast/Gigabit Ethernet, Intel Pro/Wireless 2100 802.11B wifi

Answer (score 2):

I have used Ubuntu 11.10 ona t42 and all the drivers are there, works like a dream!

Unfortunatly the T42 doesn't have a pae supporting processor so it didn't want to have 12.04 LTS installed, but I imagine there might be a work around for that somewhere.

But other than the pae issue Ubuntu works fine on a T42 which is similar enough to the T40 to almost guarantee support.

To recommend a version I would need to know the specs of the computer (CPU, RAM etc). Although if you create a live CD/DVD/USB then you can boot into it and see for yourself without making any changes to your current installations/set up.

Hope this helps,

Answer (score 1):

I had the previous LTS (lucid) flavour of Ubuntu running like a charm on my T42.
I had the same pae issue when installing precise via bootable USB, I then went with the update manager rom the system > administration > Software Sources menu and managed to have precise on my T42.

So i guess on old hardware, you'd have to install the previous LTS version (Lucid) first, and launch the update from the **System** > **Administration** > **Software Sources**.

It worked for me, but somehow messed up with the network drivers and i could not have my `eth` and wlan0 up after the install. I am still struggling with madwifi :)

This wiki's a gold mine worth digging:
http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/Category:T42

Answer (score 0):

in my experience I'm using now to write this post an UBUNTU 10.4 Lucid kernel 2.6.32....... it works fine . May be somewere you can find it in case I have an old 10.4 CD for installation